# Filter Powershell Output

Tags: powershell

I have a cmdlet which I am trying to use in my powershell script and would like to filter certain data.

```
PS C:\Program Files\Pure Storage\PowerShell\Modules\PureStoragePowerShellSDK2> Pfa2Array

Capacity           : 276668117913145
Space              : class Space {
                       DataReduction: 5.854038
                       Shared: 37859332468753
                       Snapshots: 12779406361680
                       System: 0
                       ThinProvisioning: 0.2864165
                       TotalPhysical: 97745537135134
                       TotalProvisioned: 590017911062528
                       TotalReduction: 8.203718
                       Unique: 47106798304701
                       Virtual: 421027042095616
                     }
```

If I do Pfa2Array | Select Capacity. I see the below output. Is it possible to display only the actual value and not the label

```
Capacity 
-----------
```

```
Pfa2Array | Select Capacity
       Capacity
       --------
276668117913145
```

Also how can I extract the value  for TotalPhysical which shows up under space.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Capacity`  ... PowerShell basics first lession.  ;-) :-D

Comment: `Pfa2Array | Select -Expand Capacity` should give you what you want for `Capacity`. Please copypaste the _exact_ output of `Pfa2Array | Select Space`.

Comment: `(Pfa2Array).Capacity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pfa2Array | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Capacity
```

or

```
(Pfa2Array).Capacity
```